# Closing 2 Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have Activity A. It opens Activity B that is a dialog Activity with a listview.
I want on a click of an item in the list view, the following will happen:

1. Window C will open
2. Window B will be closed
3. Window A will be closed

What is the most efficient way to do that?
(I do know that number 2 is easy (just add finish after opening activity C. Not sure about the rest).

Comment: What is driving the requirement to close Activity A and B?  You can just use a StartActivityForResult on Act. A, so B closes with a result, A's event triggers, C opens and A closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the startActivityForResult, and if the 3° happens, before finish the B send the Intent back to A with a flag indicating that should close, then close A and open C.